# Data manipulation by users

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've got a Django Web app that (potentially) processes millions of records per user.  In a nutshell, users upload files which are mapped to database fields/tables and the data is ultimately loaded into one of 5 MySQL tables.  I'm using the awesome [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) library to display the data back to the user.

In many instances data will be loaded into the app and later discovered to be incorrect in the source file.  For example, 500K records might be loaded, but in 400 records the first and last names were transposed.  Users are able to manipulate/modify a record at a time, but it's not reasonable to expect them to change 400 records manually.

Clearly this can be solved by allowing them to delete the 400 offending records and reloading a fixed source file, but this gets to the root of my problem.  How do you allow users to selectively delete (or modify) 400 records from a list of 500K based on some condition?  I'm essentially asking, "how do I allow my users to execute restricted, but arbitrary, SQL against my database without having something horrible go wrong?"

I know I could construct some kind of "SQL builder" in the Web app, but that approach seems... wrong somehow.  Is there something like a seriously restricted phpMyAdmin or SQL Buddy I could expose to my users?  I've searched for Django apps along those lines, but I've come up with nothing.  I suppose I could offer them some keyword search/filter and then allow them to delete anything that meets the criteria.

Anyone out there tackled this problem and have some guidance?  I'm genuinely stumped as to the best approach.

Comment: Are you sure that you're solving the right problem? Without a detailed analysis it's hard to be sure but my first thought is a better preview of what's going to be imported coupled with a robust undo would be a better approach.

Comment: Fair question. In many instances, the person loading the data isn't the expert on the data - simply the IT staff. I have robust checks before loading the data, but transposed name (and the like) is difficult to validate. The data is distributed to an entirely different entity for processing/analysis and logical coherence. It's that second entity that flags inconsistencies.  But by that time, the data is already in the system and needs to be modified. Further complicating factor is that each row of data is tagged with a has_been_sent flag, to keep track of what's gone out and what hasn't.

Comment: Datatables has a search feature. Can you not use that to do a text search on your columns to filter the dataset?

Comment: @fosstrack, you are right and looking at the datatables api it looks like I can return a subset of the filtered/searched data.  The issue there is that each row of data has between 30-40 data elements and not all of them are put in the datatable; rather, only those values that help the user identify unique records.  I'm only displaying 11 of the 30-40 odd elements in the datatable - the rest are not displayed.  They click on the row in the datatable to see the record details. I suppose I could add the full record detail to the datatable and hide the irrelevant columns tho.

Answer (score 0):

Who are you're users, and how much do you trust them?

- If your trust is low, you will need to expose some sort of API.
- If your trust is high, take suggestions for an admin command such as "transpose names" and give them access to that table in Django admin. then they can select batches of records to apply this command against.